# Do we “book a seat” or “buy a seat” on a train?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

I'm actually confused about “book a seat” or “buy a seat” on the second class train.

> Can we _______ a seat on the second class train?

Comment: Book means make a reservation.

Comment: Book a reservation, buy a ticket.

Comment: What does a railway website says?  [BuyingTickets](https://www.nationalrail.co.uk/times_fares/ticket_types/Train_Tickets.aspx)

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please use a dictionary to investigate the differences between book and buy, then come back to us if you still have difficulty.

Comment: In Britain, you buy a ticket to travel on the train, and you may also be able to reserve a seat (if not, you have to search for a vacant seat when you board the train).

Comment: I get it thank you very much all of you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be preferable you say "book a seat" rather than "buy a seat", because the latter would suggest that you purchased and acquired that particular seat, and now are the owner of it.